# Support both AD clients and non-AD clients concurrently

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I have Service x I make authentication for the service with membership provider

and I'm the DB and active directory users

some projects need authentication with DB or AD

but we have project need to support both so the clients can be authenticated from the internet (DB) or from the network (AD)

how I can support this ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at ["Claim based authentication (Geneva Framework)"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd278426.aspx) and ["Building Claim Based security authentication"](http://www.allfreetech.com/microsoft-net/building-a-claims-based-security-model-in-wcf-part-1-68.html)

On a high level you create two endpoints with AD and non-AD authenticaiton. Your security layer will populate claims based on user and the core of your service will use the claims for authorizaiton and will not know/care how the user authenticated.

Comment: thank you for reply , but can i make one endpoint with different authentication (Username, windows, ... )?  this is my main proplem really , I have windows client and this client can access the services from windows domain and from the internet so how i can support the two modes with one endpoint

Comment: Would need to know more about your app. Same users accessing it from intranet and internet? How does AD auth work right now, do you pick up windows credentials or do you ask the user to enter username/password/domain? Why can you have all users in AD?

Comment: we have small change , all the users from the AD , our application is domain based but some clients require to login from outside the domain from the internet and he need to login with the same user name and password of domain

Comment: So why don't you just popup a window, ask for username and a password (and a domain) and set those credentials when you create a wcf channel. I have the same situation and i only popup a login window when "silent" login fails.